# How to use a mic connected to a PC as a remote mic on a Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, audio, audio-recording

I have a macbook and windows PC, all connected to a local network. I want to connect a USB mic to PC, and be able to record audio on a mac or do zoom/skype calls using it as a remote mic. Is it possible to set up such streaming?

Comment: What's wrong with just plugging the USB mic straight into the Mac?

Comment: Just a bit more convenience when I don't have to plug and unplug it every time I want to use it. Some kind of solution to convert USB mic into Bluetooth one would work too but I imagine it will be more complicated.

Comment: It's a whole lot simpler to just move it to the other computer than it is to figure out how to broadcast it, then insert that into your audio stream; especially of you don't want to incur a half second delay.